# USB hub with stable behaviour

Tags: usb, hub

Not entirely relevant to the question but it is the problem I have encountered.

I have a notebook plugged to a monitor and I need to use a USB mouse, a USB keyboard, a USB wireless adapter (TP-LINK TL-WN722N) and a USB mini-table with coolers (my note's internal cooler isn't enough, it overheats). The notebook has only three USB ports so I bought a cheap USB hub with no visible brand.

At first, I had the keyboard and table plugged in but sadly it doesn't work well with my keyboard, keystrokes are delayed and sometimes the input is stuck and a single key gets repeated for a couple of seconds; so I've switched the mouse with the keyboard and although it works fine sometimes, every now and then the mouse doesn't respond or respond slowly with a big delay and after a couple of hours it stops working altogether. On Windows it keeps beeping that plug sound and on Linux nothing happens, on both the behavior is the same in other ports.

So my requirements are:

- At least four ports
- Works on Windows and Linux (even if it doesn't install the driver itself)
- Stable - doesn't stop working out of nowhere and/or can be reset and work again without shutting down or restarting the OS
- Recognizes printers and other devices that need drivers
- Needs to be powered, rather than drawing its power from the USB cable
- [optional] Able to transfer from/to multiple devices to/from computer
- [optional] Two USB 3.0 ports (or more)
- [optional] Able to transfer between devices plugged directly

Comment: Does stability improve if you unplug the cooler table?  It sounds like you've got another requirement: the USB hub needs to be powered, rather than drawing its power from the USB cable.

Comment: Not really. It behaves the same with sporadic delays on mouse and constant delays on keyboard. Also my computer can't shutdown with the hub plugged. Maybe the hub has a power/electronic bug. I'll add that requirement, thanks!

Comment: Just search for the highest rated hub on Amazon. Use their search tool to look for your requirements.